# jQuery form submit does not find data

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page where multiple forms are created dynamically by a database, and the purpose of the form is to submit some data to a webhook to drive an API call.

I have trawled all of the forums for days now and not found a solution to my problem - it's driving me crazy! Here is the working code - https://jsfiddle.net/Richyc84/bkmLcauv/

This shows my code is working, and each button submits to the webhook with the correct value. But when I put the code on my site (example here - http://www.bouncepost.co.uk/zapiertest/), the forms submit, but both with no data, or blank data.

If anyone can help I would really appreciate the support! (html and jQuery code below as well).

```js
jQuery('.mediainfo').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var clipid = jQuery(this).serialize()
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/641301/azvo2c/',
    type: 'post',
    data: clipid,
    success: function() {
      //whatever you wanna do after the form is successfully submitted
      jQuery('.modal').modal('hide');
      alert(clipid);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <button style="font-size:15px;width:100px;white-space:normal;padding: 
0px 0px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mediainfo1">Update 
MediaInfo1</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="mediainfo1" data-toggle="mediainfomodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 1100;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update MediaInfo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Update MediaInfo for clipid 1?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form id="form1" class="mediainfo"><input type="hidden" name="clipid" value="clip1"><input type="submit" value="Confirm" style="font- 
size:15px;width:100px;white-space:normal;padding: 0px 0px;">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->


<div>
  <div class="row">
    <button style="font-size:15px;width:100px;white-space:normal;padding: 
0px 0px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mediainfo2">Update 
MediaInfo2</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="mediainfo2" data-toggle="mediainfomodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index: 1100;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update MediaInfo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Update MediaInfo for clipid 2?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form id="form2" class="mediainfo"><input type="hidden" name="clipid" value="clip2"><input type="submit" value="Confirm" style="font- 
size:15px;width:100px;white-space:normal;padding: 0px 0px;">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Thera are also issues with loading mixed content of fine-uploader plugin:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bouncepost.knack.com/lolaclips#zapier-submission/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.bouncepost.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - I should have explained a bit more. That page is referencing script that is used for something I removed for this example. Here is the page on my actual site, and not the staging site - http://www.bouncepost.co.uk/zapiertest/

Comment: You should then pass an object jQuery.ajax call:
`data: { clipid }`